# Supported Android API levels in rosjava

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has there been any decision made on what API levels will be supported in rosjava?
The reason I ask is that I noticed the Android libraries and tutorials set
minSdkVersion to 9.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10162/supported-android-api-levels-in-rosjava/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2011-06-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should work on Android Level 8.  The Level 9 is due to the fact that the original implementation used a class that required level 9.  This has since been fixed.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-06**:
We'll have to figure out some other ways to package those sensor examples as those are constantly evolving with the API levels -- you can use the actual communication parts w/o level 9.

**Comment by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on 2011-06-05**:
The OrientationPublisher in the Android library is using TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR which is level 9.